# Sed does not exist for windows 10 64bits but?

Tags: windows-10, bash, batch, 64-bit, sed

I have the following unix script :

```
ZECOM = /path/to/command/dothis
for FILEg in *g.F
do
echo $FILEg
FILE=`echo $FILEg | sed 's/g\./\./' | sed 's/\.F/\.f/'`
$ZECOM -someoption -f ./optionsfile.sh $FILE $FILEg somelib.so 
FILEZECOM=`echo $FILE | sed 's/\.f/\.zecomextension64/'`
chmod ugo+x $FILEZECOM
done
```

that I want to translate into a batch script.

I came up with :

```
SET ZECOM = "C:\path\to\command\dothis.exe"

for %%FILEg in (*g.F) do (
    echo %%~nf
    SET FILE = `echo %%~nFILEg | sed 's/g\./\./' | sed 's/\.F/\.f/'`
    ZECOM -someoption -f %FILE% %%~nFILEg somelib.lib
    SET FILEZECOM=`echo %FILE% | sed 's/\.f/\.zecomextension64/'`
    cacls %FILEZECOM% /g everyone:f
)
```

but of course it doesn't work as `sed` is not a recognized command ... Of course, there's a 32bits gnu version of sed for windows that complains about some dll missing. So what would be my options/alternatives in this situation ?

*Some background information* :

The script looks, in its directory, for all files ending in "g.F", and for any such a file `totog.F` there is also (by construction, at the moment I want to run my script) an homologue file `toto.f` ; then the script executes the command `acommand` to which `ZECOM` points to : `ZECOM -someoption -f %FILE% %%~nFILEg somelib.lib` that is : `acommand -someoption -f toto.f totog.F somelib.lib` where `someoption` is some particular option of the command `acommand` and where the `somelib.lib` indicate that the command is to be run while linking to the library file `somelib.lib`.

This produces a file `toto.zecomextension64`. ("zecomextension64" is the extension of the produced files.) Then the `cacls` gives all rights to everyone, for the produced file. (These produced files will be executed and read by many different users through a same program they will all run in their own session.)

Basilly, I used `sed` on unix to make the string mappings `"totog.F" --> "toto.f"` and `"toto.f" --> "toto.zecomextension64"`.

Comment: For meta variables are only one letter, with distinct casing. You should explain what the script does; otherwise only people fluent in both script languages could answer. To find a pattern use findstr, to replace chars use substitution with (normal variables either in a sub or inside a (code block) using delayedexpansion.

Comment: The script looks, in its directory, for all files ending in `g.F`, and for any such a file `totog.F` there is also (by construction, at the moment I want to run my script) a homologue file `toto.f` ; then the script executes the command `acommand` to which `ZECOM` points to : `ZECOM -someoption -f %FILE% %%~nFILEg somelib.lib` that is : `acommand -someoption -f toto.f totog.F somelib.lib` where `someoption` is some particular option of the command `acommand` and where the `somelib.lib` indicate that the command is to be run while linking to the library file `somelib.lib`.

Comment: This produces a file `toto.zecomextension64`. (`zecomextension64` is the extension of the produced files.) Then the `cacls` gives all rights to everyone, for the produced file. (These produced files will be executed and read by many different users through a same program they will all run in their own session.)

Comment: Basilly, I used `sed` on unix to make the string mappings `"totog.F" --> "toto.f"` and `"toto.f" --> "toto.zecomextension64"`.

Answer (score 0):

My try, the last two commands are only echoed to test output.

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "ZECOM=C:\path\to\command\dothis.exe"

for %%F in (*g.F) do (
    echo %%~nF
    SET "FILE=%%~nF"
    echo "%ZECOM%" -someoption -f "!%FILE:~0,-1!"  "!FILE!" somelib.lib
    echo cacls "!FILE:.F=.ZECOM!" /g everyone:f
)
```

If the output looks OK remove the `echo`s

Comment: Should it be `%FILE%` instead of `"!FILE!"` ? (Because this triggers an error.) Also, the `~0,-1` triggers an error.

Comment: No the `!` are correct because you need delayedExpansion when setting **AND** echoing a variable inside a (code block). I just forgot to enable it with setlocal, answer changed.